# Material UI's Tooltip - Customization Style

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

How can I change the background color and color for Material UI's Tooltip. I tried as below but it is not working.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
tooltip: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        rippleBackgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});

import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { theme } from "my-path";

<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} >
<Tooltip
    title={this.props.title}
    placement={this.props.placement} className="customTooltipStyle">
    <em className="fa fa-info-circle"></em>
</Tooltip>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759985/how-to-style-material-uis-tooltip
I think this has what you need..

Comment: @S.Haviv - I tried already. It is not working. That's why I asked.

Comment: That other answer is from a very early version of Material-UI. I have duplicated my answer on that post as well to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are examples of how to override all tooltips via the theme, or to just customize a single tooltip using withStyles (two different examples). The second approach could also be used to create a custom tooltip component that you could reuse without forcing it to be used globally.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  createMuiTheme,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTooltip: {
      tooltip: {
        fontSize: "2em",
        color: "yellow",
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }
    }
  }
});
const BlueOnGreenTooltip = withStyles({
  tooltip: {
    color: "lightblue",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
})(Tooltip);

const TextOnlyTooltip = withStyles({
  tooltip: {
    color: "black",
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }
})(Tooltip);

function App(props) {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <div className="App">
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Tooltip title="This tooltip is customized via overrides in the theme">
            <div style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
              Hover to see tooltip customized via theme
            </div>
          </Tooltip>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        <BlueOnGreenTooltip title="This tooltip is customized via withStyles">
          <div style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
            Hover to see blue-on-green tooltip customized via withStyles
          </div>
        </BlueOnGreenTooltip>
        <TextOnlyTooltip title="This tooltip is customized via withStyles">
          <div>Hover to see text-only tooltip customized via withStyles</div>
        </TextOnlyTooltip>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Tooltip customization]

Here is documentation on tooltip CSS classes available to control different aspects of tooltip behavior: https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#css

Here is documentation on overriding these classes in the theme: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override