# Material UI - How to completely remove background \ color from tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working with Material UI's tooltip and I can't seem to figure out how to make the tooltip's background completely transparent. By default there is a grey background with white text. Changing the Tooltips background color changes the child element's background color since the Tooltip is the parent element in this context.

I've tried this

```
 <Tooltip title="Add" classes={{
    tooltip: "backgroundColor: transparent"

  }} aria-label="add">
    <Fab color="transparent" className={classes.fab}>
      <AddIcon />
    </Fab>
  </Tooltip>
```

And this:

```
<Tooltip title="Add" style={{backgroundColor: "transparent"}} aria-label="add">
    <Fab color="transparent" className={classes.fab}>
      <AddIcon />
    </Fab>
  </Tooltip>
```

My objective is to have no background on hover of the tooltip. I just want to see the text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI's Tooltip - Customization Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606764/material-uis-tooltip-customization-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only the text on hover with no background of the tooltip.

Define style like this:

```
const useStylesBootstrap = makeStyles(theme => ({
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    color: theme.palette.common.black
  }
}));
```

Use it in your React component like this:

```
const tooltipClass = useStylesBootstrap();

return (
  <Tooltip title="Add" classes={tooltipClass} aria-label="add">
    <Fab color="transparent" className={classes.fab}>
      <AddIcon />
    </Fab>
  </Tooltip>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods for customizing components, as [described in the documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/):

1. Specific variation for a one-time situation
2. Dynamic variation for a one-time situation
3. Specific variation of a component re-used in different contexts
4. Material Design variations such as with the button component
5. Global theme variation

It appears you want to use the first method and [override the style with a class](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes). To do this we'll use `makeStyles` and define a `background` for the `tooltip`, something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tooltip: {
    background: 'transparent',
  },
});

export default function ClassesNesting() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Tooltip
      classes={classes}
    >
      Button
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**APP.css**

Styles applied to the tooltip (label wrapper) element.

```
.MuiTooltip-tooltip {
    background-color: #EDEEEF!important;
    color: #2f343D!important;
  }
```