# What is the benefit of using withStyles over makeStyles?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Are there different use cases for each? When should one use withStyles over makeStyles?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**UPDATE** This question/answer is geared towards v4 of Material-UI. I have added some v5 info/links at the end.

---

The [Hook API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) (`makeStyles/useStyles`) can only be used with function components.

The [Higher-order component API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) (`withStyles`) can be used with either class components or function components.

They both provide the same functionality and there is no difference in the `styles` parameter for `withStyles` and `makeStyles`.

If you are using it with a function component, then I would recommend using the Hook API (`makeStyles`). `withStyles` has a little bit of extra overhead compared to `makeStyles` (and internally delegates to `makeStyles`).

If you are customizing the styles of a Material-UI component, using `withStyles` is preferable to wrapping it with your own component solely for the purpose of calling `makeStyles/useStyles` since then you would just be re-implementing `withStyles`.

So wrapping a Material-UI component might look like the following example (from [How to style Material-UI's tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759985/how-to-style-material-uis-tooltip/54606987#54606987)):

```
const BlueOnGreenTooltip = withStyles({
  tooltip: {
    color: "lightblue",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
})(Tooltip);
```

[image: Edit Tooltip customization]

---

For v5 of Material-UI, `styled` replaces `withStyles` and `makeStyles`. [How to style Material-UI's tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759985/how-to-style-material-uis-tooltip/54606987#54606987) contains v5 examples. I also have further discussion of v5 styling options in [Using conditional styles in Material-UI with styled vs JSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674848/using-conditional-styles-in-material-ui-with-styled-vs-jss/68675923#68675923).

Answer (score 13):

> When should one use withStyles over makeStyles?

Probably never but here are some use (narrow) cases:

- you are running an react version that doesn't support hooks
- you are writing an material-ui library and want to support older mui versions (withStyles is older than makeStyles)
- you are running an older mui version
- you want to style an class based component, for instance if you are interested in the `componentDidCatch` lifecycle method.

Comment: Nice obs, but what's the reason for _"Probably never"_ ?

Comment: means, when you are styling only your application components and already using hooks, you most likely want to use hooks there as well which means "makeStykes()"